# Avoid Multiple document.ready in Content-Master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, coding-style

I have multiple content page which are again derived form master page,

each content page need some initializer events on load and so does master page.

Currently i am doing like this

**Master page**

```
<script type="javascript"> 
$(document).ready({
// Initialize my master page events code
});
</script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphSalesTrackerScripts" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

**Content page 1**

```
 <asp:Content ID="cntBodyScripts" contentPlaceHolderID="cphSalesTrackerScripts" runat="server">
  <script type="javascript"> 
   $(document).ready({
   // Initialize my content page 1 events  code
});
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

**Content page 2**

```
 <asp:Content ID="cntBodyScripts" contentPlaceHolderID="cphSalesTrackerScripts" runat="server">
  <script type="javascript"> 
   $(document).ready({
   // Initialize my content page 2 events  code
});
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

I was learning best coding technique [Here](http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery-standards/)

and it says

> Use only one Document Ready handler per page.

so how to manage `single ready` per content page... because master page and content page are rendered together in browser and to my scenario there are `two ready handler`

Answer (score 0):

place a script in a pre-footer file and call it on all pages, then place one document.ready and move all functions, custom js stuff into there:

```
Jquery(document).ready(function() {
   // some code

   // other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a problem in using more than one `document.ready`. However, if you want to have only one, you could do two things:

1. include the placeholder inside the `<script>` tag of the master page. Then, in your content pages, you must provide only the JavaScript code, without the `<script>` tags
2. expose a callback in the main script, and provide it in the content pages. Call it from the main page if available.

The second idea looks like this:

In the master page:

```
$(document).ready({
  // Initialize my master page events code

  // run the content page callback if available
  if (window.contentCallback) { contentCallback(); };
});
```

In the content pages:

```
window.contentCallback = function() {
  // content page code to run on document.ready
};
```

Please, be aware that I'm using the global object `window` to share it between content page and master page. This is really a very bad idea, but using ASP.NET makes it necessary to do this kind of hacks.

However, you can improve it by at least including the callback in your own object, not to pollute the global with many things:

In the master page:

```
window.MyApp = {}; // Create empty object

$(document).ready({
  // Initialize my master page events code

  // run the content page callback if available
  if (MyApp.contentCallback) { contentCallback(); };
});
```

In the content pages:

```
MyApp.contentCallback = function() {
  // content page code to run on document.ready
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your MasterPage,

```
    <script src="/js/global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="AdditionalScripts" runat="server" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            initMain(window.jQuery, window); // Code in global.js
            initPage(window.jQuery, window);
        });
    </script>
```

And in all your content pages:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="AdditionalScripts">
  <script src="/js/pageX.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
</asp:Content>
```

And finally in the pageX.js :

```
function initPage($, window) {
  // Init this Page
}
```